# BASH - Print new entry to file with line number included

Tags: bash, file, line

I can't figure out how to add a line to a file then print that line only with the line number. Here is my current code which prints all lines:

```
printf "Would you like to add an entry to the file? Type yes or y? "
read addline
input=$addline
if [ $input = 'yes' ] || [ $input = 'y' ]
then
    printf "Please enter a new name: First Last: "
    read newname
    printf "Please enter a new telephone number: xxx-xxx-xxxx: "
    read phone
    printf "Please enter a street address only: xxx Example Street: "
    read street
    printf "Please enter your birthdate: xx-xx-xxxx: "
    read birth
    printf "Please enter salary: xxxxxxx: "
    read salary
    echo -e "$newname:$phone:$street:$birth:$salary" >> datafile.txt
else
    printf "\nYou did not type yes or y. Run the program again.\n"
    exit
fi
printf "\nYour entry has been saved.\n" 
sort -k2 $file | nl
```

Comment: Why do you need `input=$addline`? Why not just `read input`?

Comment: Why are you using the `-e` option to `echo`? Users don't normally enter data with escape sequences in them.

Comment: echo -e - not sure, I removed it and it works.

Comment: input = $addline - fixed it thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to help from Barmar, I figured out my answer.

cat -n $file | grep "$newname:$phone:$street:$birth:$salary"

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `-n` option to `grep` to print a matching line along with its line number.

```
grep -n -F -x "$newname:$phone:$street:$birth:$salary" datafile.txt
```

Comment: Is there a way to seperate the line number? When I enter 1:1:1:1:1 the output is 7:1:1:1:1:1. The line number looks like it is part of the entry.

Comment: You could pipe it to `sed` to replace the first `:` with space.